# Value member and DropDownStyle.DropDown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` which has a `DataSource` that is a `List<CustomClass>`. Now in this custom class, there is a property which is used as `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Now this all works very well, when i use the `DropDownStyle.DropDownList`. But what happens to the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` if I change the type to `DropDownStyle.DropDown` and input a custom text in the `ComboBox`? What will be the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` then?

**Simplified example**

```
// Create empty list of type CustomClass
List<CustomClass> comboBoxDataSource = new List<CustomClass>();

// Create a property for the selected item
CustomClass CurrentSelectedItem { get; set; }

// Use external function to fill the list with some data
LoadDataAndInsertIntoList(comboBoxDataSource);

// Set datasource, display- and value-member
cboComboBox.DataSource = comboBoxDataSource;
cboComboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
cboComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";

private void cboComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // What happens here, if using DropDownStyle.DropDown and 
   // a custom text is entered, instead of the predefined options?
   CurrentSelectedItem = (CustomClass)cboComboBox.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: maybe u need to check is dropdown or dropdownlist then only use different cast, if is dropdown maybe ( (CustomClass)cboComboBox.SelectedItem).displaymember ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my inputs:

- If you change the text, you cannot trigger
  SelectionChangeCommitted event handler.
- In order to trigger SelectionChangeCommitted you need to select the dropdown icon which list your data source which doesn't contain what you type on your combobox.
- Your data source will stay the same, since there is no modification on your datasource, displaymember or valuemember.

Comment: Which event should I then use, if I want to use my combo box as a sort auto-fill textbox?

Comment: Use KeyPress instead then from there you change your datasource.